# How to read data CRU (Climatic Research Unit) in R software?

Tags: r, database, binary

I am trying to use the climate data of the CRU database (Precipitation).

https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/precip/

The data is available as a file ".dat" format : exemple :

5 Degreee Gridded Data Set : g55wld0098.dat.gz (binary)

My question how to display them as a map (raster .tif) in R ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and here's what worked for me:

Install these two packages:

1. **cruts**
2. **raster**

then

```
library(cruts)
library(raster)
## suppose you downloaded the file cru_ts3.24.2011.2015.pre.dat.nc

rasta <- cruts2raster("cru_ts3.24.2011.2015.pre.dat.nc", 
                  timeRange=c("2011-01-01","2015-01-01"))

## there are 4 years of monthly data in this example
## so r is a RasterStack with
## 48 layers; here's January of 2011

r.2011.1 <- rasta[[1]] ## gives a plot-able object for precip Jan 2011

plot(r.2011.1) ## should look like a pretty picture

r.2012.2 <- rasta[[14]] ## gives a plot-able object for precip Feb 2012

plot(r.2012.2) ## also a pretty picture
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I just spent two weeks building out an interactive HTML mapping application using Leaflet R and other than a few odd starts and stops, it is pretty impressively easy to work with using typical geographic file types.

[Here is the link to the Leaflet PDF on Cran:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet/leaflet.pdf)

[Also rgdal a spatial data package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf)

And also a couple of great sources for r Map tutorials"

[Also this site from Ripples](https://aschinchon.wordpress.com/2016/01/07/climatic-change-at-a-glance/)

[And Zev Ross](http://zevross.com/blog/category/r/)

You should get enough from these sites to do all but the most adventurous mapping. If you get stuck after trying these tutorials and reading the PDF's post again. I will keep an eye out!

Comment: Thank you very much